# Unit testing using nose in python

Tags: unit-testing, nose

I have been trying to solve this for a long now ,but somewhere i got wrong i think and i can't identify the error.

> Problem :

Define a class '**Circle**' with the following specifications:

- Define the class method '**init**', which initializes a circle with attribute 'radius', having the following restrictions:

  - '**radius**' must be a numeric value. If not, raise TypeError with error message "radius must be a number".
  - '**radius**' must be between 0 and 1000, inclusive on both sides. If not, raise ValueError with error message "radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive".
- Define the class method '**area**', which computes the area of the circle, and returns the value rounded off to 2 decimals. Hint: Make use of the 'pi' value from the 'math' module.
- Define the class method '**circumference**', which computes the circumference of the circle, and returns the value rounded off to 2 decimals. Hint: Make use of the 'pi' value from the 'math' module.

Define a nose test class '**TestingCircleCreation**' which tests the behavior of the '**__init__**' method with the following tests:

- Define a nose test method '**test_creating_circle_with_numeric_radius**', which creates a circle with radius 2.5, and check if its radius value is 2.5.
- Define a nose test method '**test_creating_circle_with_negative_radius**', which checks if the ValueError exception is raised with the error message "radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive", while creating a circle of radius -2.5. Hint: Use assert_raises and with.
- Define a nose test method '**test_creating_circle_with_greaterthan_radius**', which checks if the ValueError exception is raised with the error message "radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive" , while creating circle of radius 1000.1 . Hint: Use assert_raises and with
- Define a nose test method '**test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius**', which checks if the TypeError exception is raised with the error message "radius must be a number", while creating circle of radius 'hello' . Hint: Use assert_raises and with.

> I have tried this but its showing error .

```py
class Circle:

def __init__(self, radius):
    # Define the initialization method below
    self.radius=radius
    if not isinstance(self.radius,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError("radius must be a number")
    elif(self.radius>1000 or self.radius<0):
        raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
    else:
        pass
def area(self):
    # Define the area functionality below
    return math.pi*(self.radius**2)
def circumference(self):
    return 2*math.pi*self.radius
    # Define the circumference functionality below
```

```py
class TestingCircleCreation:
def test_creating_circle_with_numeric_radius(self):
    c1=Circle(2.5)
    assert c1.radius==2.5

def test_creating_circle_with_negative_radius(self):
    c1=Circle(2.5)
    assert c1.radius==2.5
    with assert_raises(ValueError):
        Circle(-2.5)


def test_creating_circle_with_greaterthan_radius(self):
    c1=Circle(2.5)
    assert c1.radius==2.5
    with assert_raises(ValueError):
        Circle(1000.1)

def test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius(self):
    c1=Circle(2.5)
    assert c1.radius==2.5
    with assert_raises(TypeError):
        Circle('hello')
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestingCircleCreation:
def test_creating_circle_with_numeric_radius(self):
    c1=Circle(2.5)
    assert c1.radius==2.5

def test_creating_circle_with_negative_radius(self):
    with assert_raises(ValueError):
        Circle(-2.5)


def test_creating_circle_with_greaterthan_radius(self):
    with assert_raises(ValueError):
        Circle(1000.1)

def test_creating_circle_with_nonnumeric_radius(self):
    with assert_raises(TypeError):
        Circle('hello')
```

You are creating a circle with a radius 2.5 again in every method and then checking it whether it is equal or not. Which not require at all for other methods. Because of that, you are not able to execute the exception part. Try the above code.